# Sudoku project cant assign levels to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I stuck around 5 hours on this issue, I am trying to assign multiple levels to a Sudoku grid (one grid for 3 different levels).

But it's not working, no matter what it's giving me the result of the first function, I mean I write code with function for each level I called the levels- Baby, not so hard, nightmare
gave any one of a specific function but only one working, I gave the same function to all of them but its keep choosing the first one no matter what I am doing.

HTML Coding-

```
<form method="get" action="./bord.html"> 
  <button onclick="baby()" id="level_1" value="1">Baby</button> 
</form> 
<form method="get" action="./bord.html"> 
  <button onclick="notSoHard()" id= "level_2" type="submit" value="2">Not so 
     hard
  </button> 
</form> 
<form method="get" action="./bord.html"> 
   <button onclick="nightmare()" id= "level_3" type="submit" 
     value="3">Nightmare
   </button> 
</form>
```

```
var level =0
function baby(level){ 
    end()  
    var level = 30
    return level
}

function notSoHard(level){
    end()
 var level = 50
 return level
}notSoHard(level)

function nightmare(level){
    end()
     var level =70
     return level
}nightmare(level)

function end(){
    // debugger
 if (baby(level) == 30){
     return 30;
 }if(notSoHard(level) == 50){
     return 50;
 } if(nightmare(level) == 70){
     return 70;
 }
}
console.log(end())
```

I need that the result on the console will be what I chose( 30,50,70)
its giving me 30 all over.

God bless you

Comment: Why don't you simplify your life with a radio button that will select the level and a submit button?

Comment: You think it will work better my friend ?

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```js
function end(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const value = parseInt(event.currentTarget.value);

  var level = 0;

  if(value === 1) {
    level = 30;
  } else if (value === 2) {
    level = 50;
  } else if (value === 3) {
    level = 70;
  };

  console.log(level);

  //Add anything else you want to do with the level here

  return level;
};
```

```html
<form method="get" action="./bord.html">
    <button onclick="end(event)" id="level_1" value="1">Baby</button>
</form>
<form method="get" action="./bord.html">
    <button onclick="end(event)" id= "level_2" type="submit" value="2">Not so hard</button>
</form>
<form method="get" action="./bord.html">
    <button onclick="end(event)" id= "level_3" type="submit" value="3">Nightmare</button>
</form>
```

You only really need one function to get the value. Here, the `value` attribute of the button (1, 2 or 3) is being used to define which level to apply. You could instead pass in an argument to the `end` function to differentiate between the buttons.

Your code above would get into a stack overflow when I tried it, because the functions were calling each other recursively. It's better to keep it simple :)